# Is this the right way to do this ? I don't want to to use the prototype rather just the method on the class constructor

Tags: javascript

// Add a method to the Person's prototype called "isLegalDriver" that returns true if the person is 16 or older.

```
function Person(name, age) {

  this.isLegalDriver = function(){

    if(age >= 16){
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    };
  }
} 

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const youngPerson = new Person('Jane', 15);
console.log(youngPerson.isLegalDriver(), '<-- should be false');

const olderPerson = new Person('Joan', 16);
console.log(olderPerson.isLegalDriver(), '<-- should be true');
```

Comment: You over complicate things. You don't need a function for this job. All you need to do is `this.isLegalDriver = age > 16 ? true : false;`.

Comment: `I don't want to to use the prototype rather just the method on the class constructor` seems to conflict with `Is this the right way to do this?`. It's as if you _know_ that using the prototype is better and you're just looking for someone to say "yes this is right" anyway. _Why_ don't you want to use the prototype?

Answer (score 3):

It's not *wrong*. It creates the function on the object and that function returns the correct value.

There are changes I'd make, but it's not *wrong*:

- I'm not a fan of relying on automatic semicolon insertion, so I'd add a `;` on the end of the function assignment (and other statements, but see the next bullet point). Other people like ASI and wouldn't.
- Rather than using `if`/`else`, I'd just return the result of the comparison.

So:

```
this.isLegalDriver = function() {
    return age >= 16;
};
```

Comment: This is succinct, I didn't know JavaScript has something similar to "comprehension" in Python. Anywhere I can read or learn more on "returning the comparison result" it makes the code shorter and cleaner but might be confusing to some beginner like me but I like it lol.

Comment: @DreAdesina - I see how you got there, but it's not like a comprehension, there's no list or sequence involved. When you call the function, it does the `return age >= 16;`. The `>=` operator results in a boolean value: `true` if the `>=` relation is true and `false` if not. Since that's what you want to return from your function, returning it directly makes sense. It's just like a `sum` function doing `return a + b;`. :-)

Comment: Very understandable.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could take an IIFE and return a function with a prototype.

```js
const Person = function() {
    function p(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
  
    p.prototype.isLegalDriver = function() {
        return this.age >= 16;
    }

    return p;
}();

const youngPerson = new Person('Jane', 15);
console.log(youngPerson.isLegalDriver(), '<-- should be false');

const olderPerson = new Person('Joan', 16);
console.log(olderPerson.isLegalDriver(), '<-- should be true');
```

Comment: isn't this longer code? plus I don't want to call the property on the  Person prototype.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but simply put, this is not how you should do this job in JS. You don't need a function in the prototype. You may approach as follows;

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.isLegalDriver = age >= 16 ? true : false;
}

var youngPerson = new Person('Jane', 15);
console.log(youngPerson.isLegalDriver); // returns false

var olderPerson = new Person('Joan', 16);
console.log(olderPerson.isLegalDriver); // return true
```

But then this is silly since the age wouldn't progress and the poor guy may remain disabled from a driving license forever. You need a birth date to diff with the current date in order to to calculate the age.

And finally... yes.. you don't need this calculator to be in the instances but in the prototype.

Then you do like

```
function Person(name, birthDate) {
  this.name      = name;
  this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

Person.prototype.isLegalDriver = function(){
    return (Date.now() - Date.parse(this.birthDate)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.242199 >= 16;
}
var john = new Person("John", "7.15.1966"),
    jane = new Person("Jane", "11.24.2003");

john.isLegalDriver() // true
jane.isLegalDriver() // false
```

Comment: Did you miss the part that says `/* Do not modify code below this line */`?